# Laravel PDF Chinese Character

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fonts, dompdf

I'm using laravel and im using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf for pdf report generator, i have some proble for chinese character, but i get solve from google to import the font using this css code:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Noto Sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url("<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]; ?>/packages/digitization/fonts/fireflysung.ttf") format('truetype');
    }
    * {
        font-family: Noto Sans, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

after implement that code, it's work, it's showing the chinese character, but the load page become very slow, and when i save the PDF with 5 data on table, pdf file size reach 7Mb..

is it true? or i am doing something wrong?

Comment: try this: search the file `dompdf_config.custom.inc.php` in you dompdf library and specify: `define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_FONTSUBSETTING", true);` uncommenting this directive

Comment: i wonder what is the [charset encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) of your html. the size might come from the fonts, pdf by default embeds fonts.

Comment: Processing your document will be slow because dompdf has to get the font metrics the first time (via php-font-lib). I would expect it to get better in subsequent renders, but it may still be a bit slow for such a large font.

Answer (score 0):

I had the Chinese characters issue, in my case the blade view was showed the Chinese characters ok, but when the PDF was generated it had no Chinese characters. So I had to chance this in my blade view

```
{{ $variable_contains_chinese }}
```

to

```
{!! $variable_contains_chinese !!}
```

Also install the chinese fonts on the server.

I hope help.